# Gwt ListBox Alphabetical Order

Tags: java, gwt, listbox

I have a GWT listbox and i need to sort the contents(Strings) of listbox in alphabetical order.
What is a decent way to solve this?

I was thinking of using a Collection and Sort that or use Arrays.sort() and then populate the listbox with sorted values.Is this  a right approach?

Thanks

Comment: are you getting the values from a db? Then its better to sort it in the query itself.

Comment: I think you know the answer. I would do it also like that, but never tried it before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already said the answer and I just code it

1. [Arrays.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) the list
2. Add items to the list

Here is the code

```
String[] strings = new String[] { "ab", "ac", "a", "abc" };
java.util.Arrays.sort(strings);

ListBox l = new ListBox();

for (String s : strings) {
    l.addItem(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made the following method in a helper class:

```
public static void ListBoxAddSorted(ListBox lb, String text, String value)
    {
        int count = lb.getItemCount();
        int j;
        for ( j = 0; j < count; j++  )
        {
            String item = lb.getItemText( j );
            if ( item.compareTo( text ) >= 0 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        lb.insertItem( text, value, j );
    }
```

Basically, as you insert items to the list they are inserted in alphabetical order.  This way you can delete and add at will and your list will always be sorted.

Comment: This isn't geared for performance in bigger lists. Finding the position where an item needs to be inserted gets slower and slower as the list grows.

Answer (score 0):

Presorting doesn't work when you have many points in the application where things get added to the ListBox. You can add an event handler when it gets updated. Pseudocode:

```
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ChangeHandler;

ChangeHandler sortMyList(){

    //extract your elements, sort, then reinsert
}

ListBox lb = new ListBox();
lb.addChangeHandler( sortMyList());
```

The other alternative is to extend ListBox to a class called SortedListBox which keeps elements sorted as they are inserted. This would avoid O(n^2) amortized insertion cost.